# How does 'apt' decide how many old kernels to keep?

Tags: server, apt, kernel, purge

I'm managing a couple of servers for core services (NTP, DNS, etc) and it just occured to me that one of the servers seems to keep the 3 latest kernels, instead of 2 on the others :

```
nul@quark:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
nul@quark:~$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-51-generic       3.13.0-51.84                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic       3.13.0-52.85                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic       3.16.0-37.49~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-51-generic 3.13.0-51.84                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic 3.13.0-52.85                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic 3.16.0-37.49~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.52.59                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic      3.16.0.37.29                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image

...

nul@dwarf:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
nul@dwarf:~$ dpkg -l |grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-3.13.0-52-generic       3.13.0-52.85                     amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic       3.16.0-37.49~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-52-generic 3.13.0-52.85                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic 3.16.0-37.49~14.04.1             amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.16.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                 3.13.0.52.59                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-lts-utopic      3.16.0.37.29                     amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

All servers are maintained identically, don't know what I could have done, must be a parameter somewhere but can't find it!

Please feed my curiosity! Thank you

Answer (score 47, accepted):

**UPDATE 2022-10-03:**

It appears that Canonical/Debian has now implemented the settings directly into `apt` since version 2.4.5 to protect two kernels

```
apt changelog apt

apt (2.4.5) unstable; urgency=medium

  * Only protect two kernels, not last installed one (LP: #1968154)
  * Fix segfault in CacheSetHelperAPTGet::tryVirtualPackage()

 -- Julian Andres Klode <jak@debian.org>  Fri, 08 Apr 2022 12:22:23 +0200
```

The direct link to the bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apt/+bug/1968154

---

**Older info:**

There is a file that is auto-generated that tells `apt-get` what kernels to autoremove and which ones to keep.
The file that tells `apt-get` which kernels they are is `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` which is generated from `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal`.

Usually what happens is that when you are receiving kernel updates, when the kernel version changes, say from `3.13` to `3.16`, `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` is then updated to keep the `3.16*` kernels and is then set to remove all of the `3.13` kernels unless specified by the generating script to not be removed.

From the `apt-auto-removal` script:

```
# Author: Steve Langasek 
#
# Mark as not-for-autoremoval those kernel packages that are:
#  - the currently booted version
#  - the kernel version we've been called for
#  - the latest kernel version (determined using rules copied from the grub
#    package for deciding which kernel to boot)
#  - the second-latest kernel version, if the booted kernel version is
#    already the latest and this script is called for that same version,
#    to ensure a fallback remains available in the event the newly-installed
#    kernel at this ABI fails to boot
# In the common case, this results in exactly two kernels saved, but it can
# result in three kernels being saved.  It's better to err on the side of
# saving too many kernels than saving too few.
#
# We generate this list and save it to /etc/apt/apt.conf.d instead of marking
# packages in the database because this runs from a postinst script, and apt
# will overwrite the db when it exits.
```

However, this sometimes will not mark them for auto-removal since some of the coding has changed over versions to prevent this from happening.

If you want mark the previous kernels for `autoremove` except for the required kernels based on the scripts, run the following command from a terminal window:

```
sudo apt-mark auto ^linux-image-
```

Then, when you run the `apt-get autoremove` command only the ones that are old and no longer needed can be removed.   I have put examples below:

*This first one shows all kernels on the system minus the current running kernel.*

```
root@terrance-Linux:/home/share# dpkg -l 'linux-*' | sed '/^ii/!d;/'"$(uname -r | sed "s/\(.*\)-\([^0-9]\+\)/\1/")"'/d;s/^[^ ]* [^ ]* \([^ ]*\).*/\1/;/[0-9]/!d'
linux-headers-3.16.0-34
linux-headers-3.16.0-34-generic
linux-headers-3.16.0-36
linux-headers-3.16.0-36-generic
linux-headers-3.16.0-37
linux-headers-3.16.0-37-generic
linux-headers-4.0.0-040000
linux-headers-4.0.0-040000-generic
linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic
linux-image-3.16.0-37-generic
linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-37-generic
```

*This one shows the current running kernel.*

```
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ uname -r
4.0.1-040001-generic
```

```
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
[sudo] password for terrance: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

```
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ sudo apt-mark auto ^linux-image-
linux-image-extra-3.16.0-33-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-27-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.13.0-44-lowlatency can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.13.0-27-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.16.0-31-lowlatency can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-image-lowlatency-lts-utopic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-36-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.13.0-36-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic set to automatically installed.
linux-image-extra-3.13.0-45-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
linux-image-3.16.0-25-generic can not be marked as it is not installed.
```

**NOTE:** *The above one was too long to list, so I truncated a bit.*

```
terrance@terrance-Linux:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic linux-image-3.16.0-36-generic
  linux-image-4.0.0-040000-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-34-generic
  linux-image-extra-3.16.0-36-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 613 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n]
```

So, after running those commands, you can see that I can now auto-remove all the old but the current kernel (4.0.1-040001-generic) and the next newest one (3.16.0-37-generic).

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Ubuntu does not do auto-remove by default does it?. We do have the option but it was (still) deemed impossible to decide what an "unwanted" kernel is (on other operating system "unwanted" is equal to "unused").

Comment: Ok. I misread your post on that bit ;-)

Comment: @Rinzwind I did update it a bit.  At some point it does run the `apt-auto-remove` script to generate a new `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels`

Comment: @Terrance I tried to pass `sudo apt-mark auto ^linux-image-` followed by `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` but to no avail; however, a little `dist-upgrade` modified 2 kernels (3.13.0-52 and 3.16.0.37) and the following `autoremove` got rid of 3.13.0-51...

Comment: @ionreflex Glad you found that.  Not every answer is perfect, and it may not work for everyone.  But I find it nice that people like yourself can do a little troubleshooting and figure out a way to remove them.  I am thinking that the `dist-upgrade` you ran kicked off the `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal` which then modified the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove-kernels` then telling it which ones to keep.

Comment: @Terrance Pretty sure I did a `dist-upgrade` before, but maybe the fact that the kernels got upgraded this morning did the trick... anyway, cheers, and thank you for your answer, I've learned a lot through it!

Comment: For some reason, I was left with just the  latest kernel version instead of the two latest version. I suggest one always check what is being removed before proceeding.

Comment: Be nice if Ubuntu simply had a flag somewhere like "MAX_INSTALLED_KERNELS = 1" (meaning keep 1 additional kernel instead of ~3) in a config somewhere. This has been system-admin annoyance for MANY years. "Oh, /boot/ suddenly out of space!" 99% of time it's unused kernels laying about.

Comment: Is this still correct on Ubuntu 22? I only see `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01autoremove` and it has a `NeverAutoRemove` block in it which seems to include anything that looks like `linux-image`, `linux-firmware` or `firmware-linux`, so I'm assuming this is done differently now? Is it handled by the packages themselves?

Comment: @pzkpfw You know, I am not sure what they have done with 22.04 on lots of things.  I guess it is entirely possible that it is flipped to the kernel packages themselves now to tag themselves for autoremoval.  I guess I will have to do more research into this since I have not touched this answer since I wrote it 7 years ago.