# Partial upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 14.10

I was trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 14.10 but due to a brief wifi disconnect, at some point the upgrade failed.

Since everything was working fine and some packages were modified, I ran `apt-get upgrade` to update my packages.

When I logged in, the login screen said "Ubuntu 14.10" but when I check the Overview page in system settings, it shows "Ubuntu 14.04" Also, I am getting random errors like "You are not allowed to perform this action" when I try to change network settings or settings in the update manager.

Is there any way I can go back to 14.04 or finish my upgrade to 14.10? Or simply revert the changes that I did?

So, I ran `apt-get dist-upgrade` and here is the output that I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  fonts-unfonts-core libdb5.3:i386 libgtkdatabox-0.9.2-0 libidl-common mpg123
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Setting up brltty (5.0-2ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: Service mountkernfs has to be enabled to start service brltty
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package brltty (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.103ubuntu8) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-52-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 brltty
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Edit: I just realized that I can't mount pendrives. (Ubuntu would give the "Not authorized to perform operation" error)

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: I added the output.

Comment: Try a `sudo update-manager -d` and give me a comment with @A.B. -

Comment: @A.B. It gives a window that says "No software updates are available."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, after doing some investigation turned out to be a problematic sources list. (can be found at `/etc/apt/sources.list`) where the version was set to `trusty` and not `utopic`. This, I think, was causing the machine to download the wrong updates. So this is what I did:

- changed all instances of `trusty` in that file to `utopic`
- removed the `brltty` package as it was causing trouble with the upgrade.
- ran `sudo apt-get update` followed by `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` This installed the right version of the packages.
- Restarted the machine and now I have a nice 14.10 running on my machine.
- The kernel was not installed properly, so I removed the problematic version. [Look at this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343066/how-to-delete-a-non-working-kernel-after-update)

And now magically, all the "You are not authorized to do ..." errors are gone. Everything seems to be working fine.