# Stopping System V run level compatibility

Tags: 14.04, boot

This question is similar to the question posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/738790/stopping-system-v-runlevel-compatibility-ubuntu-14-04-lts).

The solution described above isn't working in my case because my system is failing to boot on all the kernel versions available in my grub menu. So how can i resolve this error to boot to Ubuntu 14.04 L.T.S?

For details of the error please look at this [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/reZdd.jpg)

Comment: I am trying to resolve an update issue and deleted some files inadvertently, from then on the system is not booting up. Is there a way to restore those files?

Answer (score 0):

The error messages seem to indicate that this is a missing-file problem, not a sysvinit runlevel problem.
Reinstall the missing files using apt.

Since, in your case, you are missing AppArmor files *and* you are using 14.04:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall apparmor
```

Comment: I can't boot to Ubuntu to reinstall apparmor files. I can only access the TTY nothing else. Anything i type there gives me an error message saying Login incorrect.

Comment: Unable-to-login is an entirely different problem...thought the cause may be related, and how to reset your password has been asked and answered many times here before. It is possible (though we cannot determine from the paltry information given) that you have deleted too many system-essential files, and that a full reinstall may be needed.