# Fix broken boot image

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, 17.04, 17.10

I think I did something that stopped my default ubuntu image to load USB items. This includes the following:

- Mouse
- Keyboard
- Wireless USB Adaptor

When the computer starts I get an error message, which I cannot read (because it goes away too fast).

[image: error]

When I start up if I open grub I can select an older image `4.10.0-33-generic` everything loads and works fine.

I however, want to load the default which isn't working `4.10.0-35-generic`.

Is there a way for me to fix the broken image/kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You may have two separate issues. File system corruption and secure boot...

To check the file system on your Ubuntu partition...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `sudo fsck -f /`
- repeat the `fsck` command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Stop the reboot at the BIOS and check to make sure that `secure boot` is disabled.

Comment: That didn't work. I still boot into the login screen, however, the mouse, keyboard, and wifi still do not work. Could I `purge` the image? https://askubuntu.com/a/343077/71265

Comment: Were you able to do the `fsck`? Secure boot is off? The keyboard works then, yes? Set your normal boot kernel, and set your camera to record a video, then make a short movie of the boot sequence where you see the error message that goes by too fast. Review the movie and see if you can determine what the error message says. Report back.

Comment: I was able to do the `fsck`, I am not sure how to check secure boot. The keyboard is a using the `PS/2 Port`, that still works whereas the USB keyboard does not. The error is what is above in the image.

Comment: Secure boot is a setting in your BIOS. Enter your BIOS and you may find it under a security tab, if you have a tabbed interface.

Comment: I do have a security tab, however there is no `Secure boot` setting.

Comment: You may have to Google it for your model computer. I know that ASUS kind of makes you jump through hoops to do it.

Comment: The only security settings I have are to change passwords. Looks like my Bios is from `2010`, so it is fairly old and may not have it?

Comment: They may just call it something else. If your machine came with Windows, it probably has secure boot. Google it.

Comment: It didn't come with window, as I built the computer, I bought windows 7 and put it on the computer. I can not find any information about this on google. Here is the Motherboard if that helps: https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131631

Comment: If you had Googled this, as I suggested some comments back, you'd have found this https://www.technorms.com/45538/disable-enable-secure-boot-asus-motherboard-uefi-bios-utility

Comment: That is for windows and I don't have UEFI, also I did read that when I googled

Comment: You can try booting to the previous kernel, deleting the newer kernel, and then trying Software Update again.

Comment: I finally had the courage to follow the instructions on the link I provided in my first comment, and it worked. I am able to boot into the good (older) image.